# Source Control Association Bindings Problem

Tags: version-control, visual-studio-2005, sourcesafe-6.0

I've started working on an existing project at my company that was check into VSS 6.0 about a month ago. It was built using Visual Studio 2005 and C# and references all point to .NET 2.0. I went into VSS and set my working folder as per usual and got the latest version. I've opened this project at which point I'm prompted with this:

> The solution appears to be under source control, but its binding information cannot be found. It is possible that the MSSCCPRJ.SCC file or another item that holds the source control settings for the solution, has been deleted. Because it is not possible to recover this missing information automatically, the projects whose bindings are missing will be treated as not under source control.

I click "OK" and that prompt is directly followed by this one:

> The associated source control plug-in is not installed or could not be initialized.

That presents me with these options:

1. Temporarily work uncontrolled.
2. Permanently remove source control association bindings

How can I rectify this situation? I'd like the project to remain in VSS under control. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Go to File -> Source Control -> Change Source Control, then select each project that you have under VSS and "Bind" it to the correct directory in VSS, it will prompt you for vss user name and password

Comment: This does not work for me. When I press "Bind", nothing happens at all. Also, Team Explorer prompted me to update bindings to my solution, and after I did so, folders in my entire project got reorganised. The only thing that seemed to work was adding the solution to source control again, but this way I override all files on the server.

Answer (score 5):

instead of rebinding 100s of files, have a look at this solution:
http://regev.wordpress.com/2008/03/29/binding-to-source-control-issue/

"instead of getting the latest version through the source control client, you should have opened Visual Studio and choose: File|Source Control|Open from Source Control… this would have created the solution on the second machine with no binding problems."

Answer (score 0):

Load the solution as usual and then right click on the unavailable project. Then edit the project file to comment the source control settings in the xml.
Then reload the project.

Answer (score 0):

Everything is simple:
first of all, add missing project via Source Control Explorer.
Then, make check-in.
Then add it into solution and make check-in of changed solution file.
Voila!